# D3js & CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Reference: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8dc93bce7e7200ab487d

CSS Section

```
.axis path,
.axis line 
 { fill: none; stroke: grey; stroke-width: 1; shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
```

D3JS Section

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis")
```

1. Can somebody explain class "x axis" and "y axis". I am able to see definition for "axis" in CSS but not "x axis" or "y axis" ?
2. According to CSS decedents notation ".axis[space]path" should mean any path element under an ".axis" element. But Path is not a tag in html. How should I approach this CSS notation ?

Apologies for the silly questions, please help.

Comment: Sorry! Path is a tag. Ignore question 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Following code creates a `g` element with classes `x` and `axis` and appends to the svg.
    `svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")`

`x` and `axis` are two different class names.
  The current CSS definition uses the axis class right now. So that those styles will be available for both the g elements having axis class. (Say x and y axes)

If you would like to add separate styles for each axis, you can define styles as shown below.

```
.x .axis path, .x .axis line{
   fill: red;
}
.y .axis path, .y .axis line{
   fill: green;
}
```

2) According to CSS decedents notation ".axis[space]path" should mean any path element under an ".axis" element. Path is not a tag in html.  but note that Path is a tag in html5.

Comment: Thanks Gilsha for the response. But, with no CSS definition for class "X" why should the attr code use "x axis". It should just be "axis". Isn't it. And yes, Path is a tag (my bad).

Comment: x and y class names will be helpful if you want to apply separate styles or functionality to x axis or y axis. For eg. you can select x axis using the code `svg.select(".x")`

Answer (score 0):

It means to add two classes 'x' and 'axis' to the g you just append.
.attr() can assgin multiple classes to the element, here it does not represents a selection, it is an only an assignment here.

Answer (score 0):

That's the convention followed in most of D3 examples. You were confused by the example you were viewing.

Check this example instead: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304
Specifically this part:

```
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Siddartha. This definition is more complete and easy to follow.